# Luaj: How to Import or Require a Lua Function Library

Tags: java, lua, luaj

In the Java [LuaJ library](http://luaj.org/luaj/README.html) I would like to know how to require or import a lua script of functions in another lua script called by a lua closure through Java.   For example this does not work:

```
public static LuaValue runInputStreamLua(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    Prototype luaScriptPrototype = LuaC.instance.compile(inputStream, "");
    Globals luaScriptStandardGlobals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
    luaScriptStandardGlobals.loadfile("mycoolmathfunctions.lua");
    LuaClosure luaClosure = new LuaClosure(luaScriptPrototype, luaScriptStandardGlobals);
    return luaClosure.call();
}
```

And the input stream here refers to the contents of another lua:

```
import 'mycoolmathfunctions'
-- or maybe require mycoolmathfunctions ?

return sum({1, 2, 3})
-- or maybe mycoolmathfunctions.sum({1, 2, 3}) ?
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 14):

> In the Java LuaJ library I would like to know how to require or import a lua script of functions in another lua script called by a lua closure through Java.

You can place your Lua libraries as resources in your Java packages. Then on your lua script that requires another lua script, you `require` them relative to your package path.

Here's an example:

[image]

Here's our `import-me.lua`:

```lua
-- make our sample module table global
my_imported = {}

function my_imported.printHello()
    print "Hello!"
end

return my_imported
```

Which is then imported in our `sample-that-imports.lua`:

```
require "com.example.import-me"

my_imported.printHello()
```

Then we run our `sample-that-imports.lua` in our `SampleMain` Java class:

```java
package com.example;
...
public class SampleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();

        // Again, we load the lua scripts relative to our package path
        LuaValue chunk = globals.loadfile("com/example/sample-that-imports.lua");
        chunk.call();

        // We could even use our imported library here
        chunk = globals.load("my_imported.printHello()");
        chunk.call();
    }
}
```

---

Now to answer your other problems,

> For example this does not work…

I've noticed on your Java code that you've assumed that calling `loadfile()` would automatically run your lua script. Furthermore, you've assumed that `loadfile()` is used for loading your lua modules. However, this isn't how it is supposed to be used.

Your `loadfile()` should be able to return a `LuaValue` that you need to `call()` to run the script itself. You could even safely cast it to a `LuaClosure` because this is what `loadfile()` actually returns.

To fix your Java code above, you can use this,

```
public static LuaValue runInputStreamLua(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    Prototype luaScriptPrototype = LuaC.instance.compile(inputStream, "");
    Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
    LuaClosure luaClosure = new LuaClosure(luaScriptPrototype, globals);
    return luaClosure.call();
}
```

I will assume in the above code that you are already using `require` in the `InputStream` (containing a lua script) that you have passed with the above method. If not then, you can do the following changes:

```
public static LuaValue runInputStreamLua(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    Prototype luaScriptPrototype = LuaC.instance.compile(inputStream, "");
    Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();

    LuaValue chunk = globals.load("require 'com.example.import-me';");
    chunk.call();

    LuaClosure luaClosure = new LuaClosure(luaScriptPrototype, globals);
    return luaClosure.call();
}
```

In the above changes, I am assuming that your lua module (in our example `import-me.lua`) automatically creates a global space for itself (in our example, the `my_imported` table). If not, you could do this final touch:

```
...
LuaValue chunk = globals.load("my_imported = require 'com.example.import-me';");
...
```

You also should reuse your `Globals` (returned by `JsePlatform.standardGlobals()`) unless you really want to create a new `Globals` table every time you call your method. Furthermore, if you really don't need an `InputStream`, and simply wants to load the file itself from its file path (or resource path in your Java package path), you can simplify everything into this:

```
public static LuaValue runLuaFile(Globals globals, String luafile) {
    return globals.loadfile(luafile).call();
}
```

Or to ensure that our lua module is always imported (or has been `require`'d) by our lua script,

```
public static LuaValue runLuaFile(Globals globals, String luafile) {
    LuaValue chunk = globals.load("require 'com.example.import-me';");
    chunk.call();
    chunk = globals.loadfile(luafile);
    return chunk.call();
}
```

Again, you must specify the complete resource path for our lua file. Here's a sample Java snippet using our simplified method above:

```
Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
runLuaFile(globals, "com/example/sample-that-imports.lua");
```

I hope this helps!

---

### Edit:

You've mentioned in the comments that you need to import lua modules from `InputStream`s. There are 2 ways to achieve that:

1. The first one is to load and run the lua modules that you need, like simple lua scripts – and if case that the lua modules that you need are only compatible with lua's `require` mechanism, you'll have a lot of problems to face.
2. The second, easiest, and most efficient way is to simply load the module, place it inside the lua table `package.preload`, mapped with a key as its name (to be used by `require`).

We'll use the second method above, as this is exactly what lua's `require` mechanism really intends. Here's how to implement it using LuaJ:

```
public static void preloadLuaModule(Globals globals, String modname, InputStream is) {
    LuaValue module = globals.load(is, modname, "bt", globals);
    globals.get("package").get("preload").set(modname, module);
}
```

The above utility method pre-loads an `InputStream` to be used by `require`. Here's an example usage:

Somewhere in the beginning of everything, we initialize stuffs:

```
...
preloadLuaModule(globals, "sample_module", sampleModuleInputStream);
...
```

And our `sampleModuleInputStream` above is a lua module with the following content:

```lua
-- make our sample module table global
sample_module = {}

function sample_module.printHi()
    print "Hi!"
end

return sample_module
```

Then we could simply use `require "sample_module"` anywhere we like, be it in a Lua script or in Java using LuaJ:

```java
globals.get("require").call("sample_module");
```

Comment: Thanks Jason!  Question, these lua scripts are not in our Java codebase, rather I would want to import them as text data from a database.  Can I manually pass the script source code to the globals to make it available to other scripts (pass as input streams?)

Comment: @DavidWilliams Sure you can. But you have to make sure that you have a mechanism of loading them only once. The advantage of `require` is that it loads and runs the lua module only once. You could read the lua documentation for `require`, about installing custom loaders inside `package.preload[]` table. You could also do the same in LuaJ; see the LuaJ docs for the class `PackageLib`.

Comment: Hi Jason, what does `"bt"` mean in the `preloadLuaModule` function?

Comment: Oh I see binary text.

Comment: Thanks for this! The `preloadLuaModule()` function, in particular, was just what I needed. I got luaj working by copying the `luaj` folder from the Github repo *elye/demo_android_with_lua_script* into my project, but I couldn't figure out how to make `json = require "json"`  resolve to the contents of a `json.lua` file included as an asset with my Android app. Your approach still works perfectly, *7 years* after your original post!